# Problems shrinking text in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I'm trying to have a crack at designing a simple business card using a logo which was created for me. I've run into a problem..

I had a logo made which looks pretty standard. Not sure what font is being used here. The standard size was quite large, to fit onto the business card I needed to shrink it. One for the front and one for the back, take a look at how it has turned out. I've gone from Gattaca to Guitar Hero.

Any ideas how to fix this? The middle version I dont mind. It's a bit funky, by the third variation is a bit too much..

Thanks!

[image: Something I prepared earlier..]

Comment: Change the weight of the font as you get smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you have a stroke weight in the same color and you didnt notice it, the stoke weight will remain the same when scaling and it will look good with 1pt stroke in a large logo, but when you have the same logo smaller with 1pt stroke, the stroke weight will suffocate the space around the logo. 
I attached the exmple with a different color stroke so its more obvious. 
If this is the case, you can either remove the stroke by clicking that little white square crossed with a red line below the stroke color, or you can adjust your settings in Illustrator  to change to lower stroke weight when you resize (like this: http://www.designtalkboard.com/tips/illustrator/strokewidth.php )

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the text is not *live* text, but rather *outlines*. Or... if it is live text, there's a stroke applied to it.

It seems that as you reduce the shapes the stroke applied to the shapes is not scaling. **There's a preference/setting which controls this.**

Make certain **Scale Strokes & Effects** is checked before scaling.

[image]

[image]

Or you can expand the stroke so it's a shape rather than a stroked path -- which should really be done for logos to prevent this issue from ever being a problem.